# Spring Boot Unit Test - Missing beans running test

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing

Spring Boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE.

Running the application normal works fine.

When running a Unit test, some beans are missing, for example:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in ...service.post.PostService required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

I'm using a MongoDB repository. I solved this by adding a config class which returns this bean.

After this I tried to execute the Unit test again, the following error came up:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.BasePathAwareServicesProvider required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration' in your configuration.
```

This is raised by the springfox swagger ui Rest documentation. When removing this application dependency, the test completes successfully.

What did I miss here? Some beans cannot be found or auto configured in the Unit test 'environment'.

**Update**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {}
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ProfileController.class, secure = false)
public class ProfileControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean private ProfileService profileService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ProfileController(profileService)).build();
    }

    @Test
    ....
}
```

This is the only test controller I currently have.

Comment: It seems you have had a different configurations for starting application and tests. Can you share please your application via git? I need to check your configs, without this information I can't provide you fix. Only recommendation to check your configurations (config files, annotated context configs...).

Comment: It's a private project, but I don't really have a special configuration for the test or something else. Most is auto configured with Spring Boot. See Update section for the test.

Comment: You have to annotate your ProfileControllerTest class with @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) to load the test context for the test.

Comment: Thanks, but notice that it doesn't work with @WebMvcTest.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying your code to show how to exclude a configuration that is usually required when running Unit tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {}
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ProfileController.class, secure = false, excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class) // or any other configuration.
public class ProfileControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean private ProfileService profileService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ProfileController(profileService)).build();
}

@Test
....
```

}

You can find a complete Spring Boot application that include Integration and Unit tests [here](https://github.com/a-hosseini/Automobile-Maintenance-Tracker).

Answer (score 1):

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) as a annotation for ProfileControllerTest.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on  SpringBoot Version: 2.2.5.RELEASE
This is how my issue resolved.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

@Test
public void contextLoads() {}
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
....

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProfileControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private ProfileController profileController;

@InjectMocks
private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(profileController).setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver).build();
}
@Test
....
}
```